# PowerShell: How to set culture?

Tags: powershell

I tried to `Set-Culture -CultureInfo vi-VN` but Powershell was not changed to my setted Culture.

I tested by open Powershell ISE and seen my setted Culture was changed successful.

How to make Powershell changes to my setted Culture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you've started a new session (see below):

**You may have run into a *Windows PowerShell* bug**, present as of v5.1.18362.628):

Changing to **culture `vi-VN`** (`Vietnamese (Vietnam)`, LCID `1066`), specifically<sup>[1]</sup>, **doesn't seem to work in *Windows PowerShell* (v5.1-) in *console windows***<sup>[2]</sup> (whereas it *does* work in the [obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) PowerShell ISE, as you state).

<sup>Note: The change *does* take effect for the current user account in general, but *not* in Windows PowerShell console windows.</sup>

**PowerShell [Core] 6+ is *not* affected.**

---

As for a potential fix: Windows PowerShell is no longer in active development, so only critical fixes are being implemented.
You can report Windows PowerShell bugs in the relevant [UserVoice forum](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell).

---

*Generally* speaking:

- **`Set-Culture` persistently changes the *current user*'s culture** system-wide.

  - This **only takes effect in *future* PowerShell sessions** (processes), so you'll have to open a *new* PowerShell console window, for instance, for the change to take effect.
    <sup>As of this writing, the `Set-Culture` [help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-culture) doesn't mention this requirement; fixing that is being suggested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/1730).</sup>

    - However, **the taskbar's notification area will *instantly* reflect the new culture in its date and time display**, and paying attention to that provides instant feedback as to whether the call succeeded in principle; e.g., if you run `Set-Culture fr-FR` (French), the date and time changes to something like this ("jeudi" is French for Thursday):

      - [image: taskbar date/time display in French]
    - **To start a new session**, do one of the following:

      - Open a new PowerShell console window.
      - In [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), open a new PowerShell tab.
      - In [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) installed, terminate the PowerShell Integrated Console as shown below and opt to restart it when prompted (alternatively, start a new regular (non-integrated) PowerShell instance in the integrated terminal).

        - [image: integrated terminal toolbar with delete button]
      - In the - [obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) - ISE, open a new PowerShell tab (`File > New PowerShell Tab`, <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd>).
  - While a change is *pending*, i.e. *before* you've started a new session, [`Get-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture) reports the *still effective* (old) value, not the *pending* one.
- You need to **pass the name of a predefined *specific* culture** as the (implied) `-CultureInfo` argument.

  - A *specific* culture has a name such as `fr-FR`, where `fr` designates the *language* (French) and `FR` the *location* (region or country); by contrast, a language-only culture name such as `fr` is *not* supported and *quietly ignored*.
  - To **get the list of predefined specific cultures**, run the following command or, for Windows only, consult [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c):

    - `[cultureinfo]::GetCultures('SpecificCultures')`

---

<sup>[1] Not sure if other cultures are affected as well.</sup>

<sup>[2] Running in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) doesn't help either. This suggests that the bug is inside the `ConsoleHost` PowerShell host inside of which console-based PowerShell sessions run (whereas the ISE implements its own host, `Windows PowerShell ISE Host`), as reflected in `$HOST`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To set cultures you are correct in that you should use

```
Set-Culture -CultureInfo vi-vn
```

Looking at the culture list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c) as suggested by mklement0 you will find an entire list of codes.

edit: on testing, I can see that this works for the current user, however, as mklement0 has shown in his answer there appears to be a bug where this does in fact not work.

[image]