# Powershell -Unique æ converted to ae

Tags: powershell

This is a very simple example

```
$Test = @('ae','æ')
$Test | Select-Object -Unique
```

The output

```
ae
```

What is going on here and how can I avoid it. Obviously I do not want "ae" to be equal to "æ"

Comment: Which culture / locale are you using?

Comment: I assume this concerns *Windows* PowerShell (you might explicitly **tag** this). This is indeed related to the (default) culture: `'ae' -eq 'æ'` --> `True`. See: [PowerShell: How to set culture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266401/powershell-how-to-set-culture)

Comment: It make sense with the Culture - thanks for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your current culture settings identify `ae` and `æ` as equal, so it's only returning the first one in the input array.

If you reverse the order you'll get `æ` instead:

```
$Test = @('æ','ae')
$Test | Select-Object -Unique
# æ
```

You can check which culture PowerShell is using with this:

```
PS> Get-Culture

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2057             en-GB            English (United Kingdom)
```

Although note that per @mklement0's comment, PowerShell doesn't use this culture *consistently* for everything...

> Turns out that the current culture indeed applies to Select-Object -Unique (which is currently unexpectedly also (invariably) case-sensitive). It seems that PowerShell has a split personality with respect to culture invariance: [string] casts, string interpolation and string-relevant operators (except >) use the invariant culture, whereas cmdlets use the current one.

In any case, rather than a culture-aware comparison, it sounds like what you're after is an "ordinal" comparison - for more details see [Ordinal String Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#ordinal-string-operations):

> Ordinal comparisons are string comparisons in which each byte of each string is compared without linguistic interpretation; for example, "windows" does not match "Windows".

(And by extension, `ae`, does not equal `æ`)

I can't find an idiomatic way to do that in PowerShell (you can change culture with `Set-Culture`, but all the ones I tried still treat `ae` equal to `æ`), but if you want more control over how values are compared, you could drop down into Linq like this:

```
PS> $data = @( "ae", "æ" )
PS> [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct([string[]]$data, [System.StringComparer]::Ordinal )
ae
æ
```

You've then got a whole bunch of different way to compare strings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-6.0#properties

> - **CurrentCulture** - Gets a StringComparer object that performs a case-sensitive string comparison using the word comparison rules of the current culture.
> - **CurrentCultureIgnoreCase** - Gets a StringComparer object that performs case-insensitive string comparisons using the word comparison rules of the current culture.
> - **InvariantCulture** - Gets a StringComparer object that performs a case-sensitive string comparison using the word comparison rules of the invariant culture.
> - **InvariantCultureIgnoreCase** - Gets a StringComparer object that performs a case-insensitive string comparison using the word comparison rules of the invariant culture.
> - **Ordinal** - Gets a StringComparer object that performs a case-sensitive ordinal string comparison.
> - **OrdinalIgnoreCase**   - Gets a StringComparer object that performs a case-insensitive ordinal string comparison.

and you can even implement your own:

```
class FirstLetterComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer[string] {
  [bool]Equals([string]$x, [string]$y) { return $x[0] -eq $y[0]; }
  [int]GetHashCode([string] $x) { return $x[0].GetHashCode(); }
}

# returns the first item in the list that starts with each distinct character.
# note that "abb" is omitted because it starts with the same first letter as "aaa"
# so it's not "first letter distinct".
$data = @( "aaa", "abb", "bbb" )
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct([string[]]$data, [FirstLetterComparer]::new() )
# aaa
# bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

To *add to* [mclayton's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72629392/45375), with *background information*:

- While with *cmdlets* such as `Select-Object` PowerShell does indeed use the *current* culture, **there are contexts in which it uses the *invariant* culture, notably the `-eq` / `-ne` *operators*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).
- **PowerShell has two distinct editions, and they differ with respect to the behavior at hand**, due to what edition of .NET they're built on:

  - *Windows PowerShell*, the legacy, ships-with-Windows edition, whose latest and final version is 5.1, which builds on the legacy, Windows-only *.NET Framework*, which uses **[NSL (National Language Support)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/national-language-support)** for culture-specific information.
  - [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which builds on the cross-platform *.NET 5+* edition, which now uses the **[ICU (International Components for Unicode) library](https://icu.unicode.org/)** *by default* - though [*on Windows* you can opt-into still using NLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu).

    - *Caveat*: With respect to culture-specific settings such as the default number of decimal places (`[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits`), *in effect* the NLS settings are still used; see [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) and [GitHub issue #81853](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/81853#issuecomment-1424703718).

Read on for details.

---

[`æ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86) is a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)) that is formed from the letters `a` and `e`.

- **Windows PowerShell / NLS**:

  - The **ligature `æ` is considered *equivalent* to the sequence of its *constituent letters* in *most* cultures**, ***except*** in those:

    - where `æ` is in use as a character in its own right ...
    - *and* is *not* considered equivalent to the sequence of its constituent letters.
  - These exceptions are (only the so-called *neutral* (non-nation-specific) cultures are listed, not also their national varieties):

    - da (Danish)
    - is (Icelandic)
    - kl (Kalaallisut)
    - nb (Norwegian Bokmål)
    - nn (Norwegian Nynorsk)
    - no (Norwegian)
    - se (Northern Sami)
    - sma (Sami (Southern))
    - smj (Sami (Lule))
    - smn (Sami (Inari))
    - sms (Sami (Skolt))
  - **Other ligatures have multi-letter equivalents in *all* cultures**, such as [`œ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92) vs. `oe`; there are also ligatures whose multi-letter equivalent is *not* the sequence of its constituent letters, but a modern equivalent, e.g., German [`ß`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) (which originated from `sz`) is considered equivalent to `ss`.
- **PowerShell (Core) 7+ / ICU**:

  - At least as of the ICU version that underlies PowerShell 7.2.4, **ligatures *in general* are seemingly *never* considered equivalent to their constituent letters** in string comparisons.